# In a left noetherian ring, does having a left inverse for an element guarantee the existence of right inverse for that element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, noetherian

In a left noetherian ring, does having a left inverse for an element guarantee the existence of right inverse for that element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does.

If $ba=1$ but $ab\neq 1$, then you can show $Rb\supseteq Rb^2\supseteq Rb^3\supseteq\ldots$ is an infinite descending sequence of left summands, and the complements of these summands are an infinite ascending chain.

---

*Added later*

Looking back, I'm a little appalled at not being clear about the complements.

Firstly, here is a hint about why they are summands: $b^na^nb^n=b^n$.  Secondly, let me point out that $aR\supseteq a^2R\supseteq a^3R\supseteq \ldots$ is a descending chain of right summands for similar reasons, because $a^nb^na^n=a^n$.

Thirdly, I had a specific complement in mind for each summand $Re$, and that was $R(1-e)$. Perhaps at the time it seemed clear to me that $Rf\subseteq Re$ implied $R(1-f)\supseteq R(1-e)$, but now it seems not so clear to me.

Now, it does seem that given a descending chain of summands, it is indeed possible to find an ascending chain of complements for them, but it takes a little explaining.

Instead, I would prefer to suggest an easier route:

1. As hinted above, the chain of $a^nR$ is a strictly descending chain of right summands.
2. For an idempotent $e$, the left annihilator of $eR$ is $R(1-e)$.
3. The chain $\ell.ann(a^nR)$ is a strictly ascending chain of left ideals.

Comment: But should'nt the complement of these summands be ascending chain of ideals?

Comment: Of course, all of the chains I mentioned are chains of left ideals.  What would be the point, otherwise?

Comment: Can i take the sequence R/Rx ,R/Rx^2,... Instead?

Comment: @user470412 Since each of these is isomorphic to the complement of $Rb^n$, this amounts to the same thing, but it is less clear that you have produced an ascending chain of left ideals.